# Could not find 'eventmachine'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dashing

I'm trying to install Dashing on my Linux mint.  I'm having trouble with the  gems it requires.  I've installed the Dashing gem, but when I try to run dashing I get this error about eventmachine:

```
   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'eventmachine' (~> 1.0) - did find: [eventmachine-1.0.8-java,eventmachine-1.0.0-java] (Gem::LoadError)
```

gem list: (among others)

```
eventmachine (1.0.8 java, 1.0.0 java)
```

most of my other gems, don't mention java.  I'm I pulling down the wrong gem?

thanks

Comment: Without knowing what else is in your Gemfile it's hard to help. Are you using JRuby?

Comment: no.  jruby is not installed.  I don't have a Gemfile.  I can't get to the point in which dashing creates a Gemfile.  I get the same error if I type: dashing generate mydashboard

Comment: `gem install dashing` worked w/o any issues or warnings? I'd try using rvm/rbenv with a separate gemset.

Comment: could the problem be with rubygems?  perhaps, i need to reinstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dashing makes use of a gemfile, so you should be able to install all dependencies with [Bundler](http://bundler.io/).

If you don't have it installed already, install it: `gem install bundler`

Now, `cd` into your dashboard directory.

Then, install the bundle for your dashboard: `bundle install`

Then, for good luck, run `bundle exec dashing start` to start your dashboard. This will ensure that Dashing runs from the bundle you just installed.